# Pandas conditional replace with multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to compare two columns with boolean values and replace a NaN value in a third column with 'No' if the boolean values are not equal, and 'Yes' if they are.

However, I only want to do this where there are values, i.e. not for the rows where one column has a bool and the other NaN.

This works well with only one condition. Here is a minimal working example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([[True, True, np.nan], [False, False, np.nan], 
              [False, True, np.nan], [True, False, np.nan], 
              [False, np.nan, np.nan], [True, np.nan, np.nan]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

mask = df['A'] == df['B']
df.loc[mask, 'C'] = 'Yes'

df
Out[225]: 
       A      B    C
0   True   True  Yes
1  False  False  Yes
2  False   True  NaN
3   True  False  NaN
4  False    NaN  NaN
5   True    NaN  NaN
```

When I try the opposite however, used multiple conditions, but then it also selects combinations with NaN e.g. row 5, True+NaN, whereas I only want to select the combinations True+False, or False+True. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([[True, True, np.nan], [False, False, np.nan], 
              [False, True, np.nan], [True, False, np.nan], 
              [False, np.nan, np.nan], [True, np.nan, np.nan]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

mask = df['A'] != df['B'] & df['B'].notna()
df.loc[mask, 'C'] = 'No'

df
Out[233]: 
       A      B    C
0   True   True  NaN
1  False  False  NaN
2  False   True   No
3   True  False   No
4  False    NaN  NaN
5   True    NaN   No
```

Is there a way where I can select only row 3-4 but not 5 in my second example? Ideally I'd like to apply both changes at the same time, but two steps also work, and I can merge them later.

Comment: Use `mask = (df['Classifiers'] != df['Classifiers_Clean']) & df['Classifiers_Clean'].notna()`

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately it also selects those that are True + nan, whereas I only want True + False, or False + True.

Comment: Hi. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: Unfortunately you forget for `()` -  solution is `mask = (df['A'] != df['B']) & df['B'].notna()`